# Download image for later usage (guidance)

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

What i am searching for is a method that will allow me to download an image in the browser of the user to be used latter. The image will be activated on a mouse over (hover) event. The thing is that i don't want to download the image only when the user is hovering because it creates a bad effect. It must be downloaded when the site is loading.

Any suggestions  ?

[edit] Thank you for the suggestions! I can't believe I omitted the evident solution and searched for  complicated answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like:

```
<img src="myImage.jpg" class="hidden" />
```

And set the display to `none` for the class `.hidden` in your CSS. It'll then be downloaded and won't be shown.

Then when you come to use the image it'll already be on the client.

Answer (score 2):

A common way of doing this kind of image "preload" is by the use of the JavaScript `Image` object.

```
var i = new Image;
i.onload = function() {
  console.log("Image: " + this.src + " loaded");
}
i.src = 'uri/to/file';
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called pre-loader.
You have two options, you can do it per CSS ([tutorial](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/creating-a-css-image-preloader/)), or per JavaScript ([tutorial](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column3/index.html)). One of these solutions should give you the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Check this solution:
["3 Ways to Preload Images with CSS, JavaScript, or Ajax"](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

Check this  [Preloading Images in web page](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jpreload.htm)

Answer (score 1):

just put all your images in a hidden div. The images will be automatically loaded and cached in the browser. So when you will load the image again on a mouseove , no "bad effect" will be created

```
 <div style="display:none;">
          <img src="url"  />
    </div>
```